# If $p$ divides $a^n$, how to prove/disprove that $p^n$ divides $a^n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, divisibility

The only thing I know for this problem is that an integer is a product of primes.

Comment: First show that $p$ divides $a$ [(Euclid's Lemma).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

Comment: Recall that a prime divides a product iff it divides some factor (by The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, i.e. *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations).

Comment: What are the prime factors of $a$?

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, then I have p|a, so now I can say p is a prime factor of a, then p^n certainly divides a^n. Thank you guys

Comment: @SonicFancy Right $\,a = pb\,$ so $\ a^n = (pb)^n = p^n b^n\,$ is divisible by $\,p^n.\ $ You can post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the comments.

Since we have $p$$|$$a^n$
By The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, p|a

then a = pq
hence $a^n=$(pq)$^n$ $=$ $p^n$$q^n$.

Now it is obvious that $p^n$$|$$a^n$

Answer (score 0):

If $p|a^n$ then the factorization of $a^n$ *must* look something like this: $a^n = p^n q^n r^n \ldots$ where the various bases on the right hand side are either primes or $1$, and the exponents are all $n$.

*Suppose* that $p^n$ does NOT divide $a^n$. Then the factorization of $a^n$ must be something like $a^n = p^m q^n r^n \ldots$, with $m < n$. But then the equation would be false, because then $p^m q^n r^n \ldots = p^m b^n$, where $b$ is some integer. If $1 < m < n$, then $p^m b^n$ is an Achilles number (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AchillesNumber.html), and not a perfect power, contradicting what we supposed earlier.

This may all seem very abstract, but examples should make it crystal clear. So, for example, we have $p = 2$ and $6^3 = 216$. Since $2$ divides $216$, we know that $2^3$ is also a divisor of $216$.

Of course in my answer so far I've been assuming that we're only dealing with integers. Let's try $p = 2$ like before and $a^3 = 108$. Does $2^3$ also divide $108$? It does not, but $a$ is not an integer. $a \approx 4.7622$ (or $a$ could also be one of two complex numbers that differ only in the sign of the imaginary part).